# How to overwrite field value in Kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I am using Logstash to feed data into Elasticsearch and then analyzing that data with Kibana. I have a field that contains numeric identifiers.  These are not easy to read.  How can I have Kibana overwrite or show a more human-readable value?

More specifically, I have a 'ip.proto' field.  When this field contains a 6, it should be shown as 'TCP'.  When this field contains a 7, it should be shown as 'UDP'.

I am not sure which tool in the ELK stack I need to modify to make this happen.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use conditionals and the [mutate filter](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/mutate):

```
filter {
  if [ip][proto] == "6" {
    mutate {
      replace => ["[ip][proto]", "TCP"]
    }
  } else if [ip][proto] == "7" {
    mutate {
      replace => ["[ip][proto]", "UDP"]
    }
  }
}
```

This quickly gets clumsy, and the [translate filter](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/translate) is more elegant (and probably faster). Untested example:

```
filter {
  translate {
    field => "[ip][proto]"
    dictionary => {
      "6" => "TCP"
      "7" => "UDP"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I have a question: that means, that we must store additional data in DB (in ES) ?
I prefer to use some dictionary to map my values (some ids) to strings (names of categories). I don't want to store anything additional in DB. Is it possible?

Comment: @mrarm: You can certainly store "TCP" _instead of_ "6", but if you want both field values available for searches you obviously have to store both values. The translate filter stores the lookup result in the field named in the `destination` option so it's easy to choose if you want both values or if the lookup should overwrite the original value.

Comment: I think he meant to search and agg on original values but show mapped values in visualization. It should be done after result reaches Kibana front-end and before data fed to chart component. It's 2019 now but this function is not implemented yet.